# Using XSLT to output only the id and the value of the “wert” Element?

Tags: xslt

Given the XML code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <autoverleih>
    <kunden>
      <kunde id="p1">
         <name nachname="Mustermann" vorname="Mario"/>
         <versicherung name="super1" kasko="true"/>
        </kunde>
        <kunde id="p4">
         <name nachname="Gans" vorname="Maria"/> 
         <versicherung name="die-beste" kasko="false"/>
        </kunde>
        <kunde id="p54">
         <name nachname="Gans" vorname="Gustav"/>
         <versicherung name="super1" kasko="false"/>
        </kunde>
    </kunden>
    <ausleihen>
         <vertrag kunde="p1" wert="1521.07" datum="2014-07-02" bezahlt="true"/>
         <vertrag kunde="p4" wert="397.96" datum="2014-07-12" bezahlt="false"/>
         <vertrag kunde="p1" wert="51.23" datum="2014-06-13" bezahlt="true"/>
         <vertrag kunde="p54" wert="127.12" datum="2014-08-01" bezahlt="false"/>
    </ausleihen>
   </autoverleih>
```

And the following XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform".           version="2.0">
     <xsl:template match=”autoverleih">
      <xsl:value-of select="./kunden/kunde/@id”>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match=”vertrag”> 
      <xsl:value-of select=”../kunde”/> 
      <xsl:value-of select=”./wert”/>
     </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to change this code so that for each kunde it only outputs its Id and the wert attribute.

Comment: Please add the expected output to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference `vertrag` from `kunde` I think you can use a key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:key name="vertrag-des-kunden" match="vertrag" use="@kunde"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of
      select="//kunde/@id/concat(., ': ', string-join(key('vertrag-des-kunden', .)/@wert, ', '))"
      separator="&#10;"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9HjZU

Comment: Thanks! I have thought about using a key-Element but didn’t know how to properly use it here. Can you recommend me a book/course or something similar where I can improve my skills? I really want to become proficient in using XSLT.

Comment: Several authors have published books on XSLT 1 and 2 at least, one available online as a PDF is "Practical Transformation Using XSLT and XPath (XSL Transformations and the XML Path Language)": https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm. That author also offers a video course, although not for free. Our XSLT/XPath all-star/hall of famer (I am watching too much NBA currently)  Dimitre Novatchev https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305 also has a video course: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1